# Why does "foreach" not export to my mutable object when running in parallel?

Tags: r, foreach, doparallel

I'm setting up a patient level simulation model in R. It requires generating two data frames for each patient (with and without treatment) over time (using two inner loops). I then need to loop the inner loops for each patient that is required in the model. The results of the inner loops are then stored within a list in the Global Environment.

To try and speed up the process I want to run the outer loops in parallel using the `foreach` package. The loop works as intended when using `%do%` (not running the loops in parallel). However, as soon as I set it to `%dopar%` to run in parallel, the inner loops are no longer exported to the list in the global environment and I get the error message:

> Error in { : task 1 failed - "object 'Patient_Data' not found"

I have provided code below which has a working example of the `%do%` and `%dopar%` versions of my outer loop function. The inner loops have been removed from the example and just replaced with simple probability draws.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(foreach)
library(doSNOW)

# Input
rm(list = ls())
Patient_Number <- 1000

#### Create a place to store patient data generated during the simulation ####

Patient_Data <- vector("list", length = Patient_Number)


#### Function - Non-parallel ####

Run_Sim <- function(){

  cl <- makeCluster(4, type = "SOCK")
  registerDoSNOW(cl)

  # record the time the model started

  model_start <- Sys.time()

  print(noquote(paste("Time model started: ", format(Sys.time(), "%a %d %b %Y %X"), sep = "")))

  #### Simulate Patient's BCVA scores ####

  # create progress bar

  print(noquote("Simulating Patients:"))

  pb <- txtProgressBar(min = 0, max = Patient_Number, style = 3)
  progress <- function(n) setTxtProgressBar(pb, n)
  opts <- list(progress = progress)

  foreach(i = 1:Patient_Number, .packages = c("tidyverse"), .inorder = FALSE,
          .export = ls(globalenv()),
          .options.snow = opts) %do% {

            This_Patient <- list(
              Patient_ID = 0,
              Intervention = 0,
              Comparator = 0
            )

            This_Patient_Draw_Int <- rnorm(1, mean = 50, sd = 7.8) # These normally would be more complex functions generating a data frame for each patient
            This_Patient_Draw_Comp <- rnorm(1, mean = 44, sd = 10) # These normally would be more complex functions generating a data frame for each patient

            This_Patient$Patient_ID <- i
            This_Patient$Intervention <- This_Patient_Draw_Int
            This_Patient$Comparator <- This_Patient_Draw_Comp

            Patient_Data[[i]] <<- This_Patient

          }

  # stop the progress bar

  close(pb)

  # record when model finished

  model_finish <- Sys.time()
  print(noquote(paste("Time model finished: ", format(Sys.time(), "%a %d %b %Y %X"), sep = "")))

  print(noquote(paste("Model took ", round(difftime(model_finish, model_start, units = c("mins")), 0),
                      " minute(s) to simulate ", Patient_Number, " Patients", sep = "")))

  stopCluster(cl)

}

Run_Sim()


#### Parallel version using foreach %dopar% ####

rm(list = ls())
Patient_Number <- 1000
Patient_Data <- vector("list", length = Patient_Number)

Run_Sim_Para <- function(){

  cl <- makeCluster(4, type = "SOCK")
  registerDoSNOW(cl)

  # record the time the model started

  model_start <- Sys.time()

  print(noquote(paste("Time model started: ", format(Sys.time(), "%a %d %b %Y %X"), sep = "")))

  #### Simulate Patient's BCVA scores ####

  # create progress bar

  print(noquote("Simulating Patients:"))

  pb <- txtProgressBar(min = 0, max = Patient_Number, style = 3)
  progress <- function(n) setTxtProgressBar(pb, n)
  opts <- list(progress = progress)

  foreach(i = 1:Patient_Number, .packages = c("tidyverse"), .inorder = FALSE,
          .export = ls(globalenv()),
          .options.snow = opts) %dopar% {

            This_Patient <- list(
              Patient_ID = 0,
              Intervention = 0,
              Comparator = 0
            )

            This_Patient_Draw_Int <- rnorm(1, mean = 50, sd = 7.8) # These normally would be more complex functions generating a data frame for each patient
            This_Patient_Draw_Comp <- rnorm(1, mean = 44, sd = 10) # These normally would be more complex functions generating a data frame for each patient

            This_Patient$Patient_ID <- i
            This_Patient$Intervention <- This_Patient_Draw_Int
            This_Patient$Comparator <- This_Patient_Draw_Comp

            Patient_Data[[i]] <<- This_Patient

          }

  # stop the progress bar

  close(pb)

  # record when model finished

  model_finish <- Sys.time()
  print(noquote(paste("Time model finished: ", format(Sys.time(), "%a %d %b %Y %X"), sep = "")))

  print(noquote(paste("Model took ", round(difftime(model_finish, model_start, units = c("mins")), 0),
                      " minute(s) to simulate ", Patient_Number, " Patients", sep = "")))

  stopCluster(cl)

}

Run_Sim_Para()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue by doing the following;

1. Creating a separate function which compiles the inner loops into a list
2. This list function is then passed to the `foreach` function
3. Instead of using mutable states to update an already existing list in the global environment, the `assign` function is used to pass the output of the `foreach` loop to an object called "Patient_Data" in the global environment

Example code below. Hope this helps others who may find themselves with a similar issue.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(foreach)
library(doSNOW)

# Input
rm(list = ls())
Patient_Number <- 1e4

#### Create a listing function which will be ran through "foreach" ####

list_func <- function(Patient_ID_Code){

  This_Patient <- list(
    Patient_ID = 0,
    Intervention = 0,
    Comparator = 0
  )

  This_Patient_Draw_Int <- rnorm(1, mean = 50, sd = 7.8) # These normally would be more complex functions generating a data frame for each patient
  This_Patient_Draw_Comp <- rnorm(1, mean = 44, sd = 10) # These normally would be more complex functions generating a data frame for each patient

  This_Patient$Patient_ID <- Patient_ID_Code
  This_Patient$Intervention <- This_Patient_Draw_Int
  This_Patient$Comparator <- This_Patient_Draw_Comp

  return(This_Patient)


}


Run_Sim_Para <- function(){

  cl <- parallel::makeCluster(parallel::detectCores() - 1)
  registerDoSNOW(cl)

  # record the time the model started

  model_start <- Sys.time()

  print(noquote(paste("Time model started: ", format(Sys.time(), "%a %d %b %Y %X"), sep = "")))

  #### Simulate Patient's BCVA scores ####

  # create progress bar

  print(noquote("Simulating Patients:"))

  pb <- txtProgressBar(min = 0, max = Patient_Number, style = 3)
  progress <- function(n) setTxtProgressBar(pb, n)
  opts <- list(progress = progress)

  test <- foreach(i = 1:Patient_Number, .packages = c("tidyverse"),
                  .export = ls(.GlobalEnv),
                  .options.snow = opts) %dopar% {

                    list_func(i)

                  }

  # stop the progress bar

  close(pb)

  # record when model finished

  model_finish <- Sys.time()
  print(noquote(paste("Time model finished: ", format(Sys.time(), "%a %d %b %Y %X"), sep = "")))

  print(noquote(paste("Model took ", round(difftime(model_finish, model_start, units = c("mins")), 0),
                      " minute(s) to simulate ", Patient_Number, " Patients", sep = "")))

  stopCluster(cl)

  assign("Patient_Data", test, envir = .GlobalEnv)

}

Run_Sim_Para()
```